# Как приконектить mongodb к ionic проекту?

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, angular2, mongodb, ionic

Всем привет! Нужно сделать регистрацию, используя ionic, angular и mongodb
Уже третий день пытаюсь понять где приконектить базу, чтобы отправлять в нее запросы на регистрацию. Прочитал кучу статей, везде непонятный какой-то коннект, вопрос работы непосредственно с монгой через ее запросы вообще не раскрыт. Подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно с помощью node.js:

Создадим новый проект. Для этого определим новый каталог, который будет называться mongoapp. Далее определим в этом каталоге новый файл `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mongoapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.16.0",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.0",
      "mongodb": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

В данном случае последняя зависимость - "mongodb" как раз и представляет драйвер. Всю необходимую справочную информацию конкретно по данному драйверу можно найти на https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/.

Далее перейдем к этому каталогу в командной строке/терминале и для добавления всех нужных пакетов выполним команду: `npm install`

**Подключение к базе данных**

Ключевым классом для работы с MongoDB является класс MongoClient, и через него будет идти все взаимодействия с хранилищем данных. Соответственно вначале мы должны получить MongoClient:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

Для подключения к серверу mongodb применяется метод connect():

```
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", function(err, client){
 
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    // взаимодействие с базой данных
    client.close();
});
```

Метод connect принимает два параметра:

- Адрес сервера. В качестве протокола адреса устанавливается "mongodb://". На локальной машине адресом будет localhost, после которого указывается номер порта. По умолчанию номер порта 27017.
- Второй параметр представляет функцию обратного вызова, которая срабатывает при установке подключения. Это функция принимает два параметра: err (возникшая ошибка при установке соединения) и client (ссылка на подключенный к серверу клиент).

Если при подключении возникли ошибки, то мы можем использовать значение **err** для получения ошибки.

Если же ошибки нет, то мы можем взаимодействовать с сервером через объект **client**.

В конце завершения работы с бд нам надо закрыть соединение с помощью метода **client.close()**.

Источник: https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/6.1.php

Comment: А без Экспресса и бодиПарсера никак не обойтись?

Comment: Что бы подключиться к монго? конечно можно и без них